# are computer errors inevitable?

Tags: optimization, artificial-intelligence, quantum-computing, simulation

this is my First post,I apologize for my ignorance.

The question is:
Could a programmer (human or Ai) with all the computing power and infinite time create a simulation of a world with our same laws of physics without errors of any kind (both software and hardware errors)?

Clarification:1) the simulation shouldn't simulate the computer running the simulation too, sorry for the pun. 2) if are used a quantum computer, which uses qubits, it would change something in terms of the mass of the computer or something else (like it is not as big as the universe). 3) if the computer did not simulate in real time but as a kind of movie (I think it says pre-rendered), something would change (such as the fact that it could require less computing power)

Comment: Don't know. Our mathematics is not powerful enough to prevent error. We can not define integrals for any function, only for a limited set of functions. So we are stuck with approximations only performed on numbers with only a finite amount of precision. I'm guessing error is inevitable.

Comment: You seem to be asking whether a real-time simulation of the universe is possible. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes and if It is also possible in non-real time (pre-rendered or some kind of film)